# Редирект со страниц постраничной навигации раздела на сам раздел

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Добрый день. Интересует как прописать в htaccess 301 редирект, чтобы, например, в каталоге только там, где есть в url `/catalog/` был редирект с постраничной навигации раздела на сам раздел? Т.е. чтобы, например, и с `/catalog/название_раздела/page1/` был редирект на `/catalog/название_раздела/`, и с  `/catalog/название_раздела/page2/` был редирект на `/catalog/название_раздела/`, и с `/catalog/название_раздела/page3/` был редирект на `/catalog/название_раздела/` ?

Comment: Ошибся с названием вопроса. Постраничная навигация без GET-параметров.

Answer (score 0):

Не на чем потестить, но можно примерно так:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^/catalog/(.*)/.*$  /catalog/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ок, спасибо, но не подходит, т.к. в урле могут быть /catalog/(.*)/(.*)/.*$. Нужно именно отлавливать /pageN/ и редиректить на точно такой же урл, но без /pageN/.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/catalog/(.*)/page.*$  /catalog/$1  [R=301,L]

Comment: Почему-то не отрабатывает вообще.